# Unable to open xlsx file with xlrd

Tags: python

I am getting an error file is not support in xlrd-0.7.1.

The file is saved in xlsx format

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jawed\workspace\test\Excelproject.py", line 8, in <module>
    workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 425, in open_workbook
    on_demand=on_demand,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 878, in biff2_8_load
    f = open(filename, open_mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\jawed\\workspace\\IAMarks.xls'
```

Comment: The error says that the file does not exist. Make sure you specify the file path correctly

Comment: How are you specifying the file path? What is the result of `import os;print(os.path.exists(r'C:\\Users\\jawed\\workspace\\IAMarks.xls'))`?

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't exist.

Check the location of the file before calling the function:

```
import os
if os.path.isfile(file_location):
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
else:
    # tell the user they've done something wrong
```

A possibly more Pythonic way to do it (see [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)) is in a `try`/`except` block:

```
try:
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
except IOError as error:
    print(error)
    # tell the user they've done something wrong
```